# How effective are code signing certificates when it comes to customer behavior or acceptance?

Tags: certificate

Whenever a potential customer downloads a copy of my software they get the "Unknown Publisher" warning message. I understand that if I purchase a code signing certificate this message goes away and the customer does not get the scary warning.

I'd like to know if anyone has information on how effective these code signing certificates are with regard to customer behavior. What difference did you see in customer behavior or acceptance after you signed your code using a certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from what I've seen with the software I distribute, a code signing certificate doesn't affect customer behavior much, particularly if they are downloading directly from your site and not from a 3rd party.  The customer has purposesly gone to your site, possibly even purchased your softare - they aren't not going to install your software because of an 'unknown publisher' message.

**That said**, the biggest benefit I've seen from having signed executables is anti-virus software seems less likely to falsly flag signed exe's.  My guess is there's some scoring going on, and a valid signature contributes to it.

So, ultimately, I do recommend getting a code signing cert.  You can get them much less expensively if you go through one of an issueres affiliates.

Answer (score 7):

To me "Unknown Publisher" is a red flag.  It's one more bit of "polish" on your application.

---

There's a story about a famous rock band that would give the venue a long list of requirements - things like how many electrical connections they needed, the size of the stage, placement of lights, distance to dressing rooms, etc.

Included in that list was a requirement for a bowl of M&M's candies with [all the brown ones removed](http://www.snopes.com/music/artists/vanhalen.asp).

The band couldn't care less about the candies, but the chief roadie knew if he saw a brown M&M then he couldn't trust the venue to do anything else right either.

---

**tl;dr**

As a customer I'd expect you to remove that scary message by buying and using the certificate.  If you haven't done that yet, I have to wonder what else is incomplete.

Comment: It was actually brown M&M's which were undesired. http://www.thesmokinggun.com/file/van-halens-legendary-mms-rider?page=8

Comment: @Dan - Touché your answer is spot on.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod You know, I originally typed "brown" then thought to myself, "nah, that can't be right..."  :-)  Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of points,

- Certificate per se does not make code better or safe.
- But it is very helpful in determining the authenticity and integrity of the code.

eg if there is some malicious code written by a hacker and he signs it with a certificate that does not make the code safe.

However, if you are downloading code from a known and trusted publisher and it is signed with a certificate from well known authority. It ensures that the source is correct and code has not been tampered with. It is also very effective in case of updates, as they use the same certificate that was used to distribute the software, they are automatically trusted and different operating systems use this mechanism to ensure that no malicious code is distributed as an update.